# Formatted NSDate output - Current Date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am trying to get the current date in String format. Just da date.

Here's the code and I am getting it wrong. I need a string with YYYY-mm-dd format. Just a date.

```
let date = NSDate.date()

println(date)

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
var dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

println()

let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFormat)) // This string returns no value :(
```

And second question. Will it return the date that is on the device - a current moment, or I have to specify the timezone, lime UTC or GMT+1? If a iOs user has the right date on his or her device, then specifying the time zone might not be necessary? Best practice here, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Your `date` variable (which contains the current date) is not used at all in the following calculations ....

Comment: Yes, various tests and trials including date are omitted. These lines (excluding println() of course, sorry for that) illustrate what I am doing and combining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is that `stringFromDate()` expects a *date* as argument, not a date format.
The date format has to be assigned to the `dateFormat` property of the date formatter instead.

```
let date = NSDate.date()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println(str)
```

This prints the date using the default time zone on the device. Only if you want the
output according to a different time zone then you would add for example

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
```

Comment: Yes. I see where I was wrong. Thanks. For the first line I might shorten for let date = NSDate()